# Failed dependencies trying to install package 'libxml2'

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm

I am trying to install `libxml2`, but my system complains about dependencies. The dependent packages exist on system.

The ultimate goal is to install `xml_grep2`, I have been trying various methods (`cpan`,  etc).

```
[root@testserver xml]# rpm -ivh libxml2-2.9.0-1.x86_64.rpm
  warning: libxml2-2.9.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID de95bc1f
  error: Failed dependencies:
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.9.0-1.x86_64

[root@testserver xml]# yum install glibc
  Package glibc-2.5-107.x86_64 already installed and latest version
  Package glibc-2.5-107.i686 already installed and latest version

[root@testserver xml]# find / -name libc.so.6
  /lib64/libc.so.6
  /lib/libc.so.6
  /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Please edit and add more information. What distribution and version?

Comment: The package seems to need an outdated (or newer) version of the C library. My Fedora 18 has `libxml2-2.9.0-3.fc18` and `glibc-2.16-28.fc18`, which is substantially newer. BTW, I'd be _very_ suprised if your distribution doesn't have a package for this. What do you need it for?

Comment: CentOS release 5.9 (Final)

Comment: [root@testserver App-xml_grep2-0.13]# perl Makefile.PL

Warning: prerequisite XML::LibXML 0 not found.

Warning: prerequisite XML::LibXML::XPathContext 0 not found.

Writing Makefile for App::xml_grep2

Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

Comment: [root@testserver App-xml_grep2-0.13]# yum list all | grep libxml2
libxml2.i386                               2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.6       installed
libxml2.x86_64                             2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.6       installed
libxml2-devel.i386                         2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.6       installed
libxml2-devel.x86_64                       2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.6       installed
libxml2-python.x86_64                      2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.6       base

Comment: Check this link http://xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html May be helps you

Answer (score 0):

You want to install  xml_grep2 manually. You can download it from rpm.pbone.net It can solve dependencies problem.I think you need higher version of libxml2 when you had glibc 2.5 or Downgrade glibc 2.1.x

Answer (score -1):

If you are really sure that you can work with this version you can install the rpm with --nodeps, I would prefer to instal the libxml2 with yum to ensure that the version is compatible with my libs.

Comment: Do not ever install with `--nodeps`, that is guaranteed _not_ to work (because it is missing dependencies...).

Comment: It might work, for example, if you compiled the package yourself it won't be on your package manager, the the library exists.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like issue is with manuall `libxml2` package installation and package you are trying to install is not compatible.  I suggest you to install package using yum.

```
yum install libxml2
```

Comment: WTF? yum remove glibc?